# Dropdown created via jquery ajax: how to keep the user choice after form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, drop-down-menu, selected

I populate a dropdown (dropdown2) based on the user choosing something in a first dropdown (dropdown1). Dropdown1 contains a list of partners and dropdown2 fills a list of people that belong to the partner. This is my jquery code below (it works):

```
$("select[name='dropdown1']").change(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/getPeoplebyPartner",
    data: "partnerId="+$("select[name='dropdown1']").val(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $("select[name='dropdown2']").empty();
        $("select[name='dropdown2']").append($("<option />").val("").text("select the person").attr('selected','selected').attr('disabled','disabled').attr('style','display:none;'));
        $.each(data, function() { //Filling each option
            $("select[name='dropdown2']").append($("<option />").val(this.id).text(this.name));
        });
    }
});
});
$("select[name='dropdown1']").change();
```

However if a user submits the form but there was any error anywhere, dropdown2 is repopulated but the option the user may have made there is lost. I want to fix that.

I think the best way would be to modify this part:
`$("select[name='dropdown2']").append($("<option />").val(this.id).text(this.name));`

Into:
`if(this.id == WHAT THE USER HAD SELECTED BEFORE THE FORM WAS SUBMITTED) $("select[name='dropdown2']").append($("<option />").val(this.id).text(this.name).attr('selected','selected'));
else $("select[name='dropdown2']").append($("<option />").val(this.id).text(this.name));`

How can I find what the user had selected before submitting the form?

thanks in advance!

Comment: HTML is stateless, so you'll need cookies or local storage, or just submit the form with ajax, validate serverside, return result !

Comment: Or just send the submitted value back to javascript.

Comment: @adeneo don't you mean `http` is stateless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. After the user submitted the form - using the server side you will
   need to analyze the content of the `POST` header - or if your form use
   `GET`, you will need to parse the querystring (that's something that you can also do using javascript)
2. You validate your form without the 'submit' action but by using an
   Ajax call. This Ajax call can return you an error code based on the
   error made by the user and then you can update the user interface
   accordingly.

I recommend the second option. You have a good example here: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/using-ajax-to-validate-forms/

Comment: I really like your second option since I anyway wanted to add client-side validation but without duplicating the server-side validation logic. Calling the same logic via ajax should kill all birds with one stone.